# How to get float from unsigned bytes in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, byte, unsigned

I am communicating with some device and this device sending me data as unsigned bytes. And I need to convert these bytes to float in Java. Is there any way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Every answer here is badly flawed, IMHO, because everyone is guessing that the input is in one format or another.  All that's known is that it is "unsigned bytes".  Datos, you're going to have to be more explicit about the input format if you want a good answer.  For example, I could be an idiot and assume that you meant that the input is (mathematically) integers in the range 0-255.  But then why would you want to convert it to a float?  Etc... the possible guesses are endless.  Best would be some examples: show input bytes and numeric value represented.

Comment: It's more troubling that an answer that's clearly wrong "8 bytes for a float" "shifting by multiples of 4 instead of 8 bits" has been voted up to the correct answer. @Ed Staub, you can come up with corner cases and force yourself to misunderstand practically anything, but normal people assume the most general/simplest solution when they hit a question that isn't completely detailed.

Comment: Voting to close, as the question is misleading and the answers even more so.

Comment: @LastCoder - I was presenting that as an extreme case - I thought the "I could be an idiot" made that clear to anyone who...  The point is that the data could be coming from any kind of hardware in any kind of representation - often nothing remotely like IEEE-754.  The fact that he wants it internally represented as a float says nothing about the format on the wire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) takes 32 bits as an int and converts it to a float.

All you need to do first is convert your four bytes to an `int` using the normal shift and or operations appropriate to the endianness of your data.  For example,

```
float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(
    (barr[0] & 0xff)
    | ((barr[1] & 0xff) << 8)
    | ((barr[2] & 0xff) << 16)
    | ((barr[7] & 0xff) << 24));
```

You can also use [`FloatBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer%28%29) depending on how you are receiving the data.

> ```
> public abstract FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer()
> ```
>
> Creates a view of this byte buffer as a float buffer.

Note, that "the device [is] sending me data as unsigned bytes" is not true.  The data is sending you bytes, and Java represents them as **signed** bytes.  Java does not have an unsigned byte type.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

> **byte**: The byte data type is an **8-bit signed** two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Comment: You want multiples of 8 not 4. Please correct your << 4, << 8 << 28. Every byte contains "8" bits, which is why you shift by 8 not 4.

Comment: Also note that a float usually denotes "4" bytes not "8". "8" bytes would be considered a double. Float=32bits=4bytes. Double=64bits=8bytes.

Comment: @LastCoder, thanks for pointing that out.  I just had a brain-fart after mucking around with hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

How abt http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFloat() ?

Although I would usually just lookup how it's implemented and then do it myself to avoid any overhead.

Answer (score -1):

```
Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits);
```

To get the int you just concatenate the bytes of the array into an integer

big-endian:

```
int myInt = (byte[0] << 24) |
((byte[1] & 0xff) << 16) |
((byte[2] & 0xff) << |
(byte[3] & 0xff);
```

little-endian:

```
int myInt = (byte[3] << 24) |
((byte[2] & 0xff) << 16) |
((byte[1] & 0xff) << |
(byte[0] & 0xff);
```

You should have taken the 2 seconds to search google.
https://www.google.com/?q=java+byte+array+to+float